# Why is my class not being prototype'd?

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Rectangle;


int main(){
    Rectangle myRoom(5,10);

    cout << myRoom.getHeight() << endl;
    cout << myRoom.getLength() << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

class Rectangle{
    private: 
        int height;
        int length;

    public: 
        Rectangle(int aHeight, int aLength){
            height = aHeight;
            length = aLength;
        }

        int getHeight(){
            return height;
        }

        int getLength(){
            return length;
        }
};
```

Compiler is telling me that Rectangle, getHeight, and getLength are undefined. Why is it that my class Rectangle is not being prototype'd so that I can define it under the main method? Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: first, put the Rectangle class in a header file. second, never use system("pause") it's not a good habit/practice. As to where you are wrong, it's probably because you declare your class after you main(). put them to the top after the includes

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
class Rectangle;
```

is a *forward declaration* that basically tells the compiler nothing but that class `Rectangle` exists. And since the compiler doesn't know anything else about this class, `Rectangle` is an *incomplete type*.

At this line:

```
Rectangle myRoom(5,10);
```

you are trying to create an instance of class `Rectangle` although the class `Rectangle` hasn't been defined before. Naturally, the forward declaration does not suffice in this case. The type `Rectangle` is still incomplete.

Have a look at [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/553682/1168156), you'll find there a nice explanation of what you can and cannot do with incomplete type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the class definition prior to the call to the constructor. Ideally, you'd put it in a header file.

Please get rid of the [system("pause")](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html).

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "prototyping the class" in any formal meaning of the term.

Class types can be *declared* (or forward-declared, as this sort of declaration is sometimes referred to), which is what you did by your

```
class Rectangle;
```

declaration. A class type declared in this way can only be used in very limited way. You can declare pointers and references to `Rectangle`, for one example. But you are not allowed to access any innards of such class, since the compiler knows nothing about those innards from such a declaration. You are not allowed to define objects of such class.

Class types can be *defined*, which is what you did with your

```
class Rectangle {
  ...
};
```

declaration. Once the class is *defined* (but not before), you can use it in any way you wish.

In your code you are attempting to define an object and access members of a class that has been declared, but not yet defined. This will not work and there's no way around it. You have to swap the definition of `main` and the definition of `Rectangle` in your code.

If you wish, you can define your member functions after `main` (`Rectangle::getHeight` etc.), but that's pretty much all you can do after `main`. Everything else should go before `main`.